# Fona 808 With Arduino Connections

Tags: arduino

I'm currently working with Fona808 Module with the arduino
Now i'm only testing connections with the arduino so i haven't connected my antenna nor my battery.
i'm using 2G SIM Card which works on legacy nokia so it's 2G for sure and powering the module using USB port.
Using adafruit library it connects to the module alright but the problems it cant read my SIM SSID 
isn't that supposed to work without antenna or must i connect it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've setup multiple systems running Fona's. Reading the SIM should work without connecting an antenna. However, without connecting the battery, I wouldn't expect much of anything to work.